# Salvando códigos PHP salvos no MySQL

Tags: php, html

Qual a melhor maneira de salvar pequenos códigos em PHP no banco MySQL, de forma que poderiam ser visualizados eventualmente, junto com textos salvos em HTML no banco?

Comment: Codificando com `htmlentities`

Comment: No caso você que compilar os codigos depois ?

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons acho que ele vai usar incluindo no meio do script, com alguma função, etc

Answer (score 2):

Caso você queira converter esses códigos para poder usar como exemplo em sua aplicação... Segue a dica.

---

Utiliza a função `htmlentities` para codificar o código PHP. Essa função irá converter todos os caracteres aplicáveis em entidades HTML, por exemplo:

Esse código

```
<?php
    $variable = ["A", "B", "C"];
    var_export($variable);
?>
```

Será transformado em:

```
&lt;?php

    $variable = [&quot;A&quot;, &quot;B&quot;, &quot;C&quot;];
    var_export($variable);

?&gt;
```

Feito isso, você poderá utilizar em seu HTML normalmente.

```html
Meu código:
<pre>
    <code>
    &lt;?php
        $variable = [&quot;A&quot;, &quot;B&quot;, &quot;C&quot;];
        var_export($variable);
    ?&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

Para utilizar essa função, basta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

Comment: Pessoal, agora sim ficou claro a respeito de como exibir o código PHP salvo no bd. Vou abrir uma outra pergunta abordando como Compilar o código PHP.